# How to use the same issue labels in another repository?

Tags: github

I want to apply my new issue labels to all of my repositories in Github.
I can make a new issue label (e.g. `important`) in a repository. (Let's call this repository `hello-repo`)
But I don't know how to use `important` in `bye-repo`.
Do I need to add a new label each time I create new repositories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add common issue tags as follows, note that this works only if you're in an organization account as in personal account you have to create each time (creating an org is free in GitHub)

If you're in organization account (remember you must be the owner of that org in GitHub), follow these steps..

1. Go to Settings->Repository defaults in GitHub
2. Under that you can find issue tags you want to have every time you create a repo under your org (in personal account, there's no option sadly for now)
3. You can add/remove/edit labels on your choice.

Answer (score 1):

The organisation default labels only get used when creating a new repo. You can use GitHub CLI to clone labels from one repo to another also, as explained here: https://napjose.ph/posts/copy-issue-labels-from-another-github-repository